# Can I add the "login using facebook" feature for my fb business page?

Tags: api, facebook-login

I am trying to use the developers api's for my business account with FB.. Does Facebook allow "pages" to do it? Trying to use the "login using facebook" app to my site and it is not allowing it...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Pages cannot use Apps, only users can use apps